# How to draw a graph in java using adjacency matrix

Tags: java, drawing, draw

i need to draw a graph like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHHMR.png), the input is an adjacency matrix and the output is the graph in a window, the way of another color is the way with less weight but the most importan for me is to learn to draw a simple graph. Thank you

Comment: Take a piece of paper and a pen. Draw a nice little circle for every column in the adjacency matrix. You can name them however you like. Then draw a line between any two circles for which the corresponding element in the matrix is nonzero.

Comment: Try something first before asking!

Comment: Hey what kind of solution is that @jrook hahah

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/   Please try something, and show us what you’ve tried.  We won’t write code for you, but we will help you if you are trying and go astray, get stuck, or go down the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

English is not my language sorry, maybe I did not express myself well

I found a library in python to draw a graph easily, it is called networkx and matplotlib